# How to measure very long elapsed time robustly in C

Tags: c, time

I want to measure the uptime of my application that may run for days and months. And I will report this uptime when the user requests.

I don't want to get system time by `time()` because system time can be altered by the user. I want to reliably measure how much time has passed since my application was started.

I am currently using `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, …)` on Linux and `QueryPerformanceCounter(…)` on Windows. Once during the application start, and again when the application needs to report the uptime. I believe these functions make use of the cpu's inner timers, and they may divert over long periods.

1. How much would these timers divert over, say, a month of time?
2. Is there a better and more reliable way to measure elapsed wall-clock-time, assuming there is no internet connectivity to an NTP server?

Comment: Why not periodically sample `time()` and only accumulate positive elapsed wall time?

Comment: Would that be more accurate when the system is not syncing to an ntp? How does `time()` internally update its elapsed time?

Comment: Sanity test `time()` with your `clock_gettime()` and file records to detect alterations.  When `time()` seems reasonable,use that as it is more long term accurate..  Else use `clock_gettime()` .  See [Segal's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segal%27s_law)

Comment: Why don't you contact a third party time server? (assuming the user can't interfere with the network traffic.)

Comment: If you aren't going to be able to connect to an external reliable time source, you aren't going to be able to improve on `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, …)` or equivalent for accuracy.  I'm not sure that there's a way to measure the drift over a month without an external reliable time source.  Are you sure you aren't worrying about nothing?  When uptime is measured in millions of seconds (there are about 2.5 million seconds per month), microseconds of drift isn't really going to matter, and if it does, you need the accurate external time source.

Comment: Is the uptime actually important for something or is it just an "impress users" feature? If it's actually important then it's completely reasonable to document that the software must run on a machine where clocks must be accurate, precise and not jump while running. If it's to impress users then why bother? `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is the best you can get reasonably portably. It's not great since it's not well defined and may or may not be frequency adjusted to SI seconds, but it's still probably the best you can do.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks, i just wanted to know if `clock_gettime()` was the best option, just for the sake of knowledge.


@Art it is kind of an impress feature, however there are plans to use this later for license checking in user provided plugins. Eg. system starts with network connection and license and time are verified, then network is lost and a plugin may check the uptime to decide when to expire it's license. There may be other uses in the future such as periodic operations etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "if the drift matters, you need an external time source". That is exactly what i am trying to decide, based on how much a drift is likely in a month for example. If you know a source where common cpu's average drift is given, I would be very happy and accept that as the answer.

Comment: The drift of a real-time clock depends upon the quality of its crystal, (or whatever), oscillator.  That is off-topic for SO.  A ceramic resonator that is avaiable in 1000's/$ from 'Chan's Electronic Emporium' will drift more than a hydrogen fountain clock.

Comment: Many years ago, I worked on a project where the time accuracy was very necessary.  We used an external selenium clock.  I could have lived very comfortably for the rest of my life on what that clock cost.